# Class 'SubClass' not found

Tags: php, oop

I'm having a problem with PHP's object inheritance:

I have two files, baseclass.php and subclass.php such that

```
//baseclass.php
<?php
echo "In baseclass.php\n";

class BaseClass {
  function __construct () {
    echo "In BaseClass constructor\n";
    $this->id = "NOT IMPLEMENTED";
  }
}
```

and

```
//subclass.php
<?php
require_once("PATH/baseclass.php");
echo "In subclass.php\n";

$elt = new SubClass();
echo $elt->id;

class SubClass extends BaseClass {
  function __construct () {
    echo "In the SubClass constructor\n";
    parent::__constructor();
  }
}
```

My expected result would be:

```
In baseclass
In subclass
In BaseClass constructor
In the SubClass constructor
NOT IMPLEMENTED
```

However what I get instead is

```
In baseclass
In subclass
Fatal error: Class 'SubClass' not found in (...) on line 6
```

Using either requires or includes yield the same result.
That being said if I put the BaseClass and SubClass in the same file the result is as expected. This would lead me to believe that in PHP you cannot extend a class that is defined in another folder, which seems odd. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need first to define the class and then to call it:

```
class SubClass extends BaseClass {
  function __construct () {
    echo "In the SubClass constructor\n";
    parent::__constructor();
  }
}

$elt = new SubClass();
echo $elt->id;
```

Comment: Is there a way to get around this? My class definitions are going to be quite lengthy and I'm not a fan of having my logic at the bottom of my file. Thanks!

Comment: what about defining each class in a separate file. And just include them in your logic files? you can also check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php